# Convert OkHttpClient to Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Part 1 code to call an API that run successfully but I want to implement the logic with Retrofit2.  I have done implementation in Part 2 but code always comes with response FORBIDDEN.

The URL takes text file as byte array for uploading. Can any one have a look at the code and guide me what I am doing wrong

**Part 1**

```
public void  testcall(byte[] bytesArray) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                RequestBody formBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json") , bytesArray);
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://logs-01.loggly.com/bulk/Token/tag/file_uploadTest")
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
}
```

**Part 2**

```
            public interface ApplicationLog {
             @POST("/")
                LogResponse uploadLog(@Body RequestBody body);
            }

public class ApplicationLogSender {

    private String url;

    public ApplicationLogSender(String url) {
        this.url = url;

    }

    public ApplicationLog   applicationLogSenderBuilder() {
        System.out.println("Log url" + url);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(ApplicationLog.class);
    }
}

        public void  testcall(byte[] bytesArray) {
           RequestBody formBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json") , bytesArray);
    // I also tried with "Text/plain but no success"

        LogResponse = builder.uploadLog(formBody).enqueue // This line always throw Forbidden
        }
```

Comment: are you able to check this api on postman?

Comment: which URL are you using as `baseUrl` with retrofit?

Comment: @karandeepsingh  yes it works fine in postman as well in first part.

Comment: @LordRaydenMK . URL is in my question mean first part

Comment: what about authentication headers? I don't see any in the okhttp request, but you're clearly using an APi that requires some sort of key

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque I did try the header but no success.